# Error in adding the columns of two tables: SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm stuck in this problem for quite while now. I have two tables `ItemMaster` and `ItemStock` and in `ItemStock` table I have a column `ItemId`, which is foreign key to `Id` column of `ItemMaster` table, and whenever I add new quantity in `ItemStock` table, I want that quantity value automatically gets summed with already exited quantity in the `ItemMaster` based on `ItemId` of `ItemStock` table.

ItemMaster:

```
   Id         ItemName     Quantity        
---------- -----------  ----------- 
    1           Item1       50
    2           Item2       50
```

ItemStock:

```
    Id         ItemId     Quantity        
---------- -----------  ----------- 
    1           1         20
    2           2         30
```

Query in SQL Server 2005:

```
with Developer([sum], itemid, stockid)
as 
(
    select 
       sum(stock.quantity + isNull(im.quantity, 0)) as [sum], 
       im.id as Itemid, stock.itemid as stockid 
    from ItemMaster im 
    inner join ItemStock stock on stock.itemid = im.id 
    group by im.id, stock.itemid 
)
update ItemMaster
set quantity = (Select [sum] from Developer)
```

Results in an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when
>   the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used
>   as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Could anyone please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're storing this value (which could easily be out of date, if something somehow bypasses your update code) rather than using a view (possibly an indexed view) which would always have the correct value?

Comment: Why don't you use a trigger?, That might be easier.

Comment: How the Quantity is summed in ItemMaster table. Is it the total number of quantity or the quantity with respect perticular ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you missing a `WHERE` clause in your UPDATE statement??

Right now, if you do a `SELECT * FROM Developer`, you get:

```
sum itemid  stockid
 70   1        1
 80   2        2
```

and that's exactly what the error says - the query returns more than a single results, so what is the UPDATE supposed to do with this?? It cannot set the `quantity` column to more than a single value.....

Just guessing - do you maybe mean to do this?

```
;WITH Developer.......
(
     ......
)
UPDATE dbo.ItemMaster
SET quantity = dev.sum
FROM Developer dev
WHERE dbo.ItemMaster.ItemId = dev.ItemId
```

Add the `WHERE` clause to associate one row from `Developer` with a single row in `ItemMaster`

Answer (score 0):

Your select return more than one records because you use a simple join, so you should insert a where clause to filter by id. Something like that

```
select sum(stock.quantity + isNull(im.quantity,0)) as [sum], im.id as Itemid, stock.itemid as stockid from ItemMaster im inner join ItemStock stock on stock.itemid = im.id group by im.id, stock.itemid
where im.id = @MyId and stock.itemid = @MyID2
```

I would also remove the other fields in the select, because you do not need them. Leave only the sum (a select more clear imo)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW ItemsOnHand
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT ItemID,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity,COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    FROM dbo.ItemStock
```

This view would always be correct. If performance is a concern, you could also index this view (on `ItemID)`, which would mean that SQL Server would maintain it as a hidden table, automatically adjusting the quantity value as rows are inserted, deleted or updated in the `ItemStock` table.